# Is iCal sync possible in java? How to connect ical server using java?

Tags: java, ios, icalendar, ical4j

I am about to build a simple iphone app. In that we are syncing iCal. I want to sync iCal in server side in java and store events in database.

I do not know is it possible to sync iCal using  java. Iphone user will send 
access token  or anything which I will use to get all calender events from ical.
Please help me I am new in this.

Sync ical events are  possible in java? If yes then give me some hint.

Comment: Sameer, were you ever able to find a java solution for syncing iCal in Java?

Comment: No, it is not possible to connect ical through JAVA.  ical4j is used to read and write .ics file. But direct communication with ical server or apple not possible yet from java or server side

Answer (score 1):

ICal parsing is possible in Java 
See http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

Comment: hi Sangram  thanks, but I already checked this link, can you please explain in details. like how to authenticate user, or what is "mycalendar.ics" file.

Comment: ical4j is only for read/write ".ics" file. I do not want to do this